# Javascript setInterval execution in less than 1 ms?

Tags: javascript

I  have this example that compares the performance of a simple counter loop using for loop and using setInerval, the exeuction time difference is huge as follows:

```
var i = 0;
var i2 = 0;
var int1 = null;

console.time("for loop");
do{  
  i++;
}while(i <= 1000);
console.timeEnd("for loop"); 


function fnc(){
  if(i2++ == 1000){
    clearInterval(int1);
    console.timeEnd("interval loop");
  }
}

console.time("interval loop");
int1 = setInterval(fnc , 1);
```

**Outputs**

[image]

See demo at: http://jsbin.com/jusiqilayi/edit?js,output

I would like to know if it is possible to execute a function using setInterval with a timespan less than 1ms? or is there a way to achieve better performance for the given example using setInterval?

Comment: I've been looking at your question for more than 5 minutes now and I just don't understand why would someone want to use the `setInterval` method in this example? or maybe I just don't get the question?!

Comment: The question is about the bottom line of setInerval performance, is it possible to get a better execution time for simple 1 instruction code as simple as increasing a variable? hope it's more clear now.

Comment: as @Ismail answered below the minimum delay is 4ms (you can try doubling your condition value to see the effect) also the whole point of using interval is to create a delay before each call, using it without a delay logically wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, omitting the delay is not the point, however what about using 0.5ms or 0.01ms as delay? maybe it is possible to achieve better performance than the 4ms stated in @Ismail answer

Comment: again that wouldn't make sense 'cause that's about as long as it'd take to normally run any function

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` are forced to use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay, `DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE`, is 4 ms which is specified by the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers) and is consistent across browsers released in 2010 and onward.

In modern browsers you can use `window.postMessage()` as a workaround to implement a 0 ms timeout as [described here](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that, do you know if it is possible to break below the 4ms delay limit?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't (As far as I know). Try the `window.postMessage()` workaround.

Comment: Thank you @Ismail.