# setTimeout() & setInterval() not working properly

Tags: javascript

Please consider the following example.

```js
var secondsCount = 0;
if( secondsCount <= 1800 )
{
   setInterval(function(){
     secondsCount++; 
     console.log( secondsCount ) 
   }, 1000);
}
```

If we run the above code nearly to 1800 seconds ( 30 mins ) we could see that **secondsCount** value & actual seconds ( or minutes ) lapsed are not equal.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Late_timeouts) might help understand why.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Klímačka: I need to show login popup before 1 min of session timeout. For that i need to maintain a counter variable.

Comment: these methods were never made to serve as a chronometer. you have to use Date() to check the real time elapsed

Comment: @MrJ: Thanks, please can you provide a simple code example ?

Comment: Then do something like `setTimeout(function () { showPopup(); }, 29 * 60 * 1000);` and do not count by a second. But anyway, it would be better to get this info from server via polling because it is unsafe to base login state on clientside code.

Comment: If you want the question to get reopened, you should ask an actual question.

Comment: I have answering to your complete question here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220342/call-javascript-function-on-every-second-nearly-1800-seconds-settimeout-se/55244510#55244510  so, please read it and answering how this suits you, and check if this answer is useful, consider if you validate...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
var secondsCount = 0;

var x = setInterval(function() {
    secondsCount++; 
    console.log(secondsCount);

    if (secondsCount >= 1800) {
        clearInterval(x);
    }

}, 1000);
```

Note that, **setInterval** and **setTimeout** are forced to use at least the minimum delay. See [Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Late_timeouts). In practice, there's no guarantee that your callback will be called in the "exact" set amount of time.

Comment: You'll get more votes if you include an explanation about what your code is doing and how it solves the OP's problem. Additionally, make sure you code is formatted as cleanly as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will do it ASAP.

Comment: @EimranHossainEimon: I tried above code but not working properly for FireFox 65. If you run the code snippet you will see milliseconds are Increasing.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166858/javascript-setinterval-execution-in-less-than-1-ms